# Finding alternatives for jsch-0.1.55.jar, since it does not dohmac-md5 and aes256-cbc

Tags: java, linux, encryption, ssh, jsch

Disclaimer: I new to these things and so I am very confused about the terminology. Forgive me if I misuse terminology.

I am writing a grails application that uses jsch-0.1.55.jar as a dependency. For the sake of clarity let us say that this application sits on server 1. Recently, the server that it communicates with via ssh has had a change and so now we must communicate with it using hmac-md5 and aes256-cbc. Let us refer to that as server two.

Our current solution is to remove these lines from the /etc/ssh/sshd_config on server two, but we need to find a way to make this work with these lines being added back. The lines:

```
Ciphers aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
```

Our build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache", {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.0.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    // profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    compile "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:3.0.10"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.14.0"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.14.0"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.14.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.14.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.14.0"
   
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13'
    compile 'org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:4.0.0.M1'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:2.5.8'
   // runtime files('libs/jsch-0.1.51.jar', 'libs/ant-jsch.jar')
   // compile files('libs/jsch-0.1.51.jar', 'libs/ant-jsch.jar')

    implementation 'com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.2.4'
    runtime 'com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.2.4'
}
```

OS for server two:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server"
```

Errors:

```
Job GRAILS_JOBS.refresh.ReflogsJob threw a JobExecutionException:
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:111)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:336)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:333)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:278)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:151)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:213)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at refresh.ReflogsJob.getLogs(ReflogsJob.groovy:66)
    at refresh.ReflogsJob.execute(ReflogsJob.groovy:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:590)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:320)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHBase.openSession(SSHBase.java:279)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:312)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Job GRAILS_JOBS.refresh.ReftasksJob threw a JobExecutionException:
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:111)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:336)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:333)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:278)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:151)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:213)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at refresh.SshService.$tt__connectTo(SshService.groovy:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1011)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:994)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:97)
    at refresh.SshService$_connectTo_closure2.doCall(SshService.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    at refresh.SshService.connectTo(SshService.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:179)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at refresh.ReftasksJob$_execute_closure1.doCall(ReftasksJob.groovy:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2296)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2281)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2322)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$186.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at refresh.ReftasksJob.execute(ReftasksJob.groovy:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:590)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:320)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHBase.openSession(SSHBase.java:279)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:312)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/mwiede/jsch?

Comment: No but it seems to be a good solution. I am new to java so I am a bit confused as to how to go about installing this. Can I just add it to my build.gradle?

Comment: yes you can simply add it as compile dependency (remove the implementation and runtime). But you have to make sure, that you only have one jsch implementation on the classpath. In order to do this, try searching the dependency tree from "gradle dependencies" output.